# Defining an index when using JavaScript push on arrays

Tags: javascript

When creating new arrays in JavaScript, I typically use `push`, but I need to define the index of each object being added to the array.

For example:

```
     var array = [];
     _.each(items, function(item) {
        array.push(item);
     });
```

With the above, I'm not defining the index of each item added to the array.

I've tried this:

```
     var array = [];
     _.each(items, function(item) {
        array[item.id] = item;
     });
```

But i end up with an empty array.  Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Show us the `items` - what ids do they have? Are they not numerically?

Comment: Ahhh, no it's not an integer actually.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to see the data.

In particular, what is 'item.id'?  Is it an integer value?

Do you really mean to use an object, which is /similar/ to a hash table?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using underscore.js, you can define your iterator function as

```
function(item, index){
  ..
}
```

And it will fill in the index variable for you.

```
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
_.each(items, function(d, i){ console.log(d, i); });
// a 0
// b 1
// c 2
```